# Q Is it possible to Fade Out a widget, randomise it, then fade it back in again?

Tags: flutter

This is my code (I'm very new to this so likely it's a bit messy, but it was doing everything I wanted up to the transition element.

What I'm looking to do is, take a list item, which is randomly generated on button press, fade it out and then back in again as a different random item from the list....then when you click again, it fades out, randomises it and fades back in again.

Currently it will change the list item then fade out on button press, then when you press again it will fade in as a new random list item.

```
var element = 'what oil do you need.';
  final _random = new Random();
  var fade = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
          setState(() {
            element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
            fade =! fade;
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: 15,
                child: Container(
                  width: 350,
                  height: 350,
                  child: Image.asset('images/tealoildrop.png'),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: fade?1:0,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                child: Text('$element',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Sacramento',
                  fontSize: 35,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Its got to have something to do with this from setState

```
fade =! fade;
```

because I'm telling it that whatever is stored in the var fade, to return the opposite....I just don't know how to turn it from true to false to true again in one command...although I could be completely wrong with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fade = !fade means turn fade value to false if it's true or viceversa, that's a correct usage for a bool. Can you try below code? I set it false then added a delay then set it true.

```
var element = 'what oil do you need.';
  final _random = new Random();
  var fade = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FlatButton(
        onPressed: (){
        setState(() {
        element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
        fade=!fade;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () 
          {setState(() {fade=!fade;});});
         });
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                top: 15,
                child: Container(
                  width: 350,
                  height: 350,
                  child: Image.asset('images/tealoildrop.png'),
                ),
              ),
              AnimatedOpacity(
                opacity: fade?1:0,
                duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                child: Text('$element',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Sacramento',
                  fontSize: 35,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the bracket conventions here right? Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
               setState(() {fade=!fade;}); looks like there are not enough close brackets?

Comment: Sorry probably because of copy-paste mistake, Edited in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Lunedor, totally pointed me in the right direction!!

So it didn't quite do what I expected, but with a little more tweaking I found that this has the perfect effect

```
    onPressed: () {
  setState(() {
    fade = !fade;
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds:2, milliseconds: 500),(){
      setState(() {
        fade=!fade;
        Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50),(){
          setState(() {
            element = list[_random.nextInt(list.length)];
```

It fades out slowly, paused (and changes the list item in the background) then slowly fade back in with the new item!

Comment: I am glad if I could help, you can accept my answer if it is correct for your question.